# Como obtener información especifica de un XML

Tags: c#, xml

Tengo problema al manejar un archivo XML, estoy intentando extraer una información especifica del siguiente archivo XML

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\n
<ax:AxFileInfo xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" objref=\"80:076596EA55DABE9F09E884549D1303B5EF22FD85C0FB02223D7DA709A279B2460BEDC1D4BD462634DEB4606555C5390EB14509254FE736A6\" filetype=\"FT_ForeignFile\" subtype=\"IFT_UNKNOWN\" size=\"2727\" formname=\"\" orgname=\"usuario.png\" subpages=\"1\" hastext=\"false\" hasanno=\"false\" ismice=\"false\" ismcold=\"false\" xmlns:ax=\"http://www.emc.com/ax\" />"
```

Necesito extraer lo que contiene el valor `filetype`.

Estoy haciendo uso del método `GetElementsByTagName`

```
XmlDocument xmlInfo = new XmlDocument();
xmlInfo.LoadXml(docInfo);
string xmlInfoString = xmlInfo.GetElementsByTagName(
                        "ax:AxFileInfo")[0].InnerXml.
                        Replace("xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"", "").
                        Replace("xsi:", "");
```

Desconozco como hacer el uso correcto del método mencionado anteriormente.

Hacer uso `GetElementsByTagName` toma el valor de lo que contiene la etiqueta, pero necesito obtener el `filetype` valor del archivo xml.

También hice uso de `InnerText` pero aún no hay resultado

```
XmlDocument xmlInfo = new XmlDocument();
xmlInfo.LoadXml(docInfo);
    string xmlInfoString = xmlInfo.GetElementsByTagName(
                            "ax:AxFileInfo")[0].InnerText.
                            Replace("xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"", "").
                            Replace("xsi:", "");
```

He estado buscando en Google, pero todo lo que obtengo es confundirme un poco más ya que todos los ejemplos que encuentro son con listas de varios elementos y solo quiero acceder a uno que será único.

Agradecería que me ayuden a obtener este valor específico, quizás allí entenderé todo el funcionamiento de XML con C#.

**Actualización:**

También probé con el método `SelectSingleNode`, pero aun no se consigue el resultado de obtener el valor.

```
string xmlInfoString = xml.SelectSingleNode("/AxFileInfo/@filetype").Value;
                Replace("xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"", "").
                        Replace("xsi:", "");
```

Comment: `GetElementsByTagName``funciona exactamente como para lo que parece. Obtiene elementos por tag de nombre. Si el tag es "titulo" obtendrá el valor de dicho titulo. -> https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_get.asp

Comment: Haciendo uso de `GetElementsByTagName` toma el valor de lo que contiene la etiqueta, pero necesito obtener lo que contiene el valor `filetype` del archivo xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que lo que intentas obtener no es un *tag* sino un *atributo*.
El método que estás buscando es [`XmlElement.GetAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.getattribute?view=netcore-3.1).

A continuación la forma de utilizarlo:

```
XmlDocument xmlInfo = new XmlDocument();
xmlInfo.LoadXml(docInfo);

XmlElement root = xmlInfo.DocumentElement;
if(root.HasAttribute("filetype"))
{
    string xmlInfoString = root.GetAttribute("filetype");
    // a partir de aquí tienes el valor 'FT_ForeignFile' en la variable xmlInfoString
}
```